# After Mule app is restarted it is receiving all messages again from Azure event hub

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-eventhub, mule4, mule-connector

We have an Azure event hub and I use Mule Azure Service Bus connector 3.2.1 with Anypoint studio 7.11.1 and Mule 4.
We created a mule app with mule 4.4.0 (the codes below).
Connection works fine and the app (thru the azure service bus "message listener") gets every message from event hub on particular topic.

**My concern is that when i restart the app, it gets every message from event hub including those that are received before.**

I have tried by adding azure service bus "receive" (so hopefully the app will not get it again next time), but I got an error of "AZURE-SERVICE-BUS-MESSAGING:LOCK_TOKEN_NOT_FOUND" from event hub since  the lockToken is "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" (which it gets from message listener in the first place).
I read this article: [this article](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Azure-Service-Bus-Connector-Abandon-Delivery-not-found-on-the-receive-link-Mule-4) https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Azure-Service-Bus-Connector-Abandon-Delivery-not-found-on-the-receive-link-Mule-4 and changed the connector version to 3.1.0, still get the same error of "AZURE-SERVICE-BUS-MESSAGING:LOCK_TOKEN_NOT_FOUND".
Here is the code (with azure service bus "receive" added) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http"
    xmlns:ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core"
    xmlns:azure-service-bus-messaging="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/azure-service-bus-messaging" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core/current/mule-ee.xsd http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/azure-service-bus-messaging http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/azure-service-bus-messaging/current/mule-azure-service-bus-messaging.xsd">
    <azure-service-bus-messaging:config name="Azure_Service_Bus_Messaging_Connector_Config" doc:name="Azure Service Bus Messaging Connector Config" doc:id="e2f8ebc0-a6c8-46ef-a1f4-cea60d5e6448" >
        <azure-service-bus-messaging:sas-connection namespace="${eventhub.name}" sharedAccessKeyName="${eventhub.serviceKey}" sharedAccessKey="${eventhub.accesskey}" />
    </azure-service-bus-messaging:config>
    <configuration-properties doc:name="Configuration properties" doc:id="70ec97a1-f9bd-4178-a15e-89d4d1a37c13" file="${mule.env}.yaml" />
    <global-property doc:name="Global Property" doc:id="5cc462ae-af0d-4702-a72d-e91d21efe2c3" name="mule.env" value="dev" />
    <http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_configuration" doc:name="HTTP Request configuration" doc:id="6e1db046-7950-4242-aae7-47ff60f3834e" >
        <http:request-connection host="localhost" port="8083" />
    </http:request-config>
    <flow name="sys-event-hub-listener-flow" doc:id="ae8e10fc-e1e2-4330-92f8-e05dfcbbe4ea" >
        <azure-service-bus-messaging:message-listener doc:name="Message listener" doc:id="5850d0ae-d3a4-425b-93c9-e3cead3714f6" config-ref="Azure_Service_Bus_Messaging_Connector_Config" ackMode="AUTO" destinationName="user-crm/ConsumerGroups/user-crm-mulesoft-consumer-group/Partitions/0" numberOfConsumers="1" outputMimeType="application/json">
            <reconnect />
        </azure-service-bus-messaging:message-listener>
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="52fb5bfc-23ed-4927-a79c-e683ec2d06be" >
            <ee:message >
            </ee:message>
            <ee:variables >
                <ee:set-variable variableName="lockToken" ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
attributes.lockToken]]></ee:set-variable>
                <ee:set-variable variableName="onePayload" ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
    payload: payload,
    hitId: attributes.properties.hitId.array,
    topic: attributes.properties.kafka_topic.array,
    timeStamp: attributes.properties.kafka_timestamp.array
    
    }]]></ee:set-variable>
            
</ee:variables>
        </ee:transform>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="ba7c30a0-6cde-4acd-9a9d-dafb7763b487" message="#[payload]"/>
        <azure-service-bus-messaging:complete-message doc:name="Complete" doc:id="b3babc6b-2cdb-4109-ba39-08e8f2b287f7" config-ref="Azure_Service_Bus_Messaging_Connector_Config" lockToken="#[vars.lockToken]" />
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="383f214a-1bed-4ab7-a324-5214f00d1da7" message="Sent Acknowledgement"/>
    
</flow>
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_config" doc:name="HTTP Listener config" doc:id="7e9718d6-12e3-46f2-a614-7106095c5985" >
        <http:listener-connection host="localhost" port="8082" />
    </http:listener-config>
    
</mule>
```

I tried AUTO on the listener (and remove "Complete" or azure-service-bus-messaging:complete-message), and the error as below:

```
DEBUG 2022-08-25 08:13:16,132 [ReactorThread73feee5b-9ec1-40de-ab19-2ff901632186] [processor: ; event: ] com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.amqp.ReceiveLinkHandler: onDelivery: linkName:Receiver_eb2ac7_075c0bf0913e4b858b98217424917420_G10S3, updatedLinkCredit:1, remoteCredit:0, remoteCondition:Error{condition=null, description='null', info=null}, delivery.isPartial:false
DEBUG 2022-08-25 08:13:16,132 [ReactorThread73feee5b-9ec1-40de-ab19-2ff901632186] [processor: ; event: ] com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.primitives.CoreMessageReceiver: Received a delivery '' from 'user-crm/ConsumerGroups/user-crm-mulesoft-consumer-group/Partitions/0'
DEBUG 2022-08-25 08:13:16,132 [ReactorThread73feee5b-9ec1-40de-ab19-2ff901632186] [processor: ; event: ] com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.primitives.CoreMessageReceiver: Received a message from 'user-crm/ConsumerGroups/user-crm-mulesoft-consumer-group/Partitions/0'. Adding to prefecthed messages.
DEBUG 2022-08-25 08:13:16,145 [pool-14-thread-9] [processor: ; event: ] com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.primitives.CoreMessageReceiver: Returning the message received from 'user-crm/ConsumerGroups/user-crm-mulesoft-consumer-group/Partitions/0' to a pending receive request
INFO  2022-08-25 08:13:16,145 [[MuleRuntime].uber.09: [sys-event-hub].Mule Azure Service Bus Messaging Connector - Message Listener Scheduler @54aa8c36] [processor: ; event: ] com.mulesoft.connector.azure.messaging.internal.source.ReceiverTask: null
DEBUG 2022-08-25 08:13:16,145 [[MuleRuntime].uber.09: [sys-event-hub].Mule Azure Service Bus Messaging Connector - Message Listener Scheduler @54aa8c36] [processor: ; event: ] com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.primitives.CoreMessageReceiver: Receiving maximum of '1' messages from 'user-crm/ConsumerGroups/user-crm-mulesoft-consumer-group/Partitions/0'
DEBUG 2022-08-25 08:13:16,145 [ReactorThread73feee5b-9ec1-40de-ab19-2ff901632186] [processor: ; event: ] com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.primitives.CoreMessageReceiver: Sent flow to the service. receiverPath:user-crm/ConsumerGroups/user-crm-mulesoft-consumer-group/Partitions/0, linkname:Receiver_eb2ac7_075c0bf0913e4b858b98217424917420_G10S3, updated-link-credit:1, sentCredits:1
INFO  2022-08-25 08:13:16,150 [[MuleRuntime].uber.07: [sys-event-hub].sys-event-hub-listener-flow.CPU_INTENSIVE @2f7f1931] [processor: sys-event-hub-listener-flow/processors/2; event: ae3f5e10-2477-11ed-a4e4-ac675d320d35] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: TimeStamp=2022-08-22T15:27:57.595 - 1661200077596
INFO  2022-08-25 08:13:16,151 [[MuleRuntime].uber.07: [sys-event-hub].sys-event-hub-listener-flow.CPU_INTENSIVE @2f7f1931] [processor: sys-event-hub-listener-flow/processors/3/route/0/processors/0; event: ae3f5e10-2477-11ed-a4e4-ac675d320d35] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Legit payload
INFO   [processor: sys-event-hub-listener-flow/processors/4; event: ae3f5e10-2477-11ed-a4e4-ac675d320d35] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: Sent Acknowledgement
DEBUG [processor: ; event: ae3f5e10-2477-11ed-a4e4-ac675d320d35] com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.MessageReceiver: Completing message with lock token '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
DEBUG 2022-08-25 08:13:16,154 [[MuleRuntime].uber.05: [sys-event-hub].sys-event-hub-listener-flow.BLOCKING @317bc21] [processor: ; event: ae3f5e10-2477-11ed-a4e4-ac675d320d35] com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.primitives.CoreMessageReceiver: Updating message state of delivery '????????????????' to 'Accepted{}'
INFO  2022-08-25 08:13:16,154 [[MuleRuntime].uber.05: [sys-event-hub].sys-event-hub-listener-flow.BLOCKING @317bc21] [processor: ; event: ae3f5e10-2477-11ed-a4e4-ac675d320d35] com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.primitives.CoreMessageReceiver: Delivery not found for delivery tag '????????????????'. Either receive link to 'user-crm/ConsumerGroups/user-crm-mulesoft-consumer-group/Partitions/0' closed with a transient error and reopened or the delivery was already settled by complete/abandon/defer/deadletter.
ERROR 2022-08-25 08:13:16,154 [[MuleRuntime].uber.05: [sys-event-hub].sys-event-hub-listener-flow.BLOCKING @317bc21] [processor: ; event: ae3f5e10-2477-11ed-a4e4-ac675d320d35] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.exception.OnErrorPropagateHandler: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Delivery not found on the receive link.
Element               : sys-event-hub-listener-flow/source @ sys-event-hub:sys-event-hub-app.xml:21 (Message listener)
Element DSL           : <azure-service-bus-messaging:message-listener doc:name="Message listener" doc:id="5850d0ae-d3a4-425b-93c9-e3cead3714f6" config-ref="Azure_Service_Bus_Messaging_Connector_Config" ackMode="AUTO" destinationName="user-crm/ConsumerGroups/user-crm-mulesoft-consumer-group/Partitions/0" numberOfConsumers="1" outputMimeType="application/json">
<reconnect></reconnect>
</azure-service-bus-messaging:message-listener>
Error type            : MULE:SOURCE_RESPONSE_SEND
FlowStack             : 
Payload Type          : [B
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Delivery not found on the receive link.
```

Comment: At the risk of repeating myself in every question, it is not a "Mulesoft app" because it is not an application developed or owned by MuleSoft. It is your application, deployed in a Mule runtime, which is a MuleSoft product.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I have added "We created a mulesoft app (the codes below)." sentence. Hopefully that make it clearer.

Comment: Mule application is clearer, not MuleSoft app. What is the exact Mule version? (examples 4.2.1, 4.3.0, 4.4.0?)

Comment: it's 4.4.0. I have just updated the post with this info too.

Comment: Why the listener is configured in automatic mode `ackMode="AUTO"` but the flow uses manual confirmation? (with `complete-message`)

Comment: Thanks Aled. for pointing that out. The manual confirmation ("complete") is an addition that i tried since "auto" on the listener did not resolve the issue (that i put in bold). So, yeah, after you pointed out, I tried "manual" on the listener and "complete" at the end, it errored out on "complete" with "AZURE-SERVICE-BUS-MESSAGING:LOCK_TOKEN_NOT_FOUND" message as specified in my original post.

Comment: Have you tried using auto and remove the lockToken and the complete-message operation?

Comment: AUTO errored out as below:<BR> INFO   Sent Acknowledgement 
MessageReceiver: Completing message with lock token '00000000'
CoreMessageReceiver: Updating message state of delivery '???' to 'Accepted{}'
CoreMessageReceiver: Delivery not found for delivery tag '???'. Either receive link to '..../Partitions/0' closed with a transient error and reopened or the delivery was already settled by complete/abandon/defer/deadletter.
ERROR Message               : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Delivery not found on the receive link.

Comment: And you removed the complete-message operation too? Please add the full error box from the application log -which provides additional context for the errors- to the question so it is readable. Not sure if you are adding them but avoid using `<br>` tags in the posts, they break code.

Comment: Yes. i removed the complete-message operation and set AUTO on the listener. The better error log has been included in the original question at the top. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I added an article https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Azure-Service-Bus-Connector-Abandon-Delivery-not-found-on-the-receive-link-Mule-4  and tried connector 3.1.0, still the same problem. I have updated my question post as such.

Comment: Connector version 3.2.1 should contain the fixes in previous versions like 3.1.0, unless there is a regression. If there is a bug it should be reported to MuleSoft.

Comment: I have alerted mulesoft on this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a Service Bus connector to connect to Event Hub, the two services are considerably different.
With Event Hub, you have a data stream for which you need to commit offsets for in order to have a track on where the client is currently receiving at.
The above is handled using the Event Hub SDK client by commiting the offsets to a storage account that then the client can use in order to start pulling data from the last commited offset.

Since the Mule connector for Service Bus might not have this capability, everytime you restart the client, it will start pulling from the beginning again.

I don't see any built in connector for Event Hub from Mulesoft, however, there is a Kafka connector that you can leverage https://docs.mulesoft.com/kafka-connector/4.6/

Comment: Thank you for your response. I thought if i can get the right lockToken (not all zeros), i would then be able to ACK and hopefully when i restart the app, i will not get the messages that have been ACKnowleged before. Is there anywhere, perhaps, in the eventHub server setup, to make sure it gives non-zero lockToken?
And yes, on Mulesoft's azure service bus connector, there does not seem anywhere  for an offset.
On your suggestion for using a kafka connector, i will try to play around with it. Thank you.

Comment: There is no concept of "lock token" for Event Hubs, that is merely related Service Bus Peek-lock receive mode.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-transfers-locks-settlement#peeklock

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Mulesoft replied to me that there is no answers for this right now. I've suggested mulesoft to make a event hub connector. I've switched to kafka connector and so far it works great for our needs in both directions. Thanks again all.